# How could make radio checkbox diabled in angular 2+ with css?

Tags: css, angular

The solution to making disabled input radio checkbox disabled with a condition in angular with css

`<input type="radio" [ngClass]="{cssClass: expression}" />`

```
.cssClass{
   color:#f2f2f2;
   cursor: default;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can trget the disable radio like this `input[type="radio"]:disabled`, and you just need to set the disable attribute bse of expression like this `[disabled]="expression "`

```css
input[type="radio"]:disabled{
   cursor: default;
   pointer-events: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:disabled +span{
   color:#f2f2f2;
   cursor: default;
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

template

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" [disabled]="true" />
    <span>Option 1</span>
</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3e3ndh)